# Iteratively add elements to a list

Tags: python, list, iterator, variable-assignment

I am trying to add elements of a list in Python and thereby generate a list of lists. Suppose I have two lists `a = [1,2]` and `b = [3,4,5]`. How can I construct the following list:

```
c = [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5]] ?
```

In my futile attempts to generate `c`, I stumbled on an erroneous preconception of Python which I would like to describe in the following. I would be grateful for someone elaborating a bit on the conceptual question posed at the end of the paragraph. I tried (among other things) to generate `c` as follows:

```
c = []
for i in b:
   temp = a
   temp.extend([i])
   c += [temp]
```

What puzzled me was that `a` seems to be overwritten by temp. Why does this happen? It seems that the `=` operator is used in the mathematical sense by Python but not as an assignment (in the sense of := in mathematics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating a copy; `temp = a` merely makes `temp` reference the same list object. As a result, `temp.extend([i])` extends the *same list object `a` references*:

```
>>> a = []
>>> temp = a
>>> temp.extend(['foo', 'bar'])
>>> a
['foo', 'bar']
>>> temp is a
True
```

You can build `c` with a list comprehension:

```
c = [a + [i] for i in b]
```

By concatenating instead of extending, you create a new list object each iteration.

You could instead also have made an actual copy of `a` with:

```
temp = a[:]
```

where the identity slice (slicing from beginning to end) creates a new list containing a shallow copy.